# Installing library with foreign architecture

Tags: package-management, software-installation, libraries, architecture, arduino

I have been trying to install libc6-i386 on ubuntu 16.04 using:
`sudo apt-get install libc6-i386` and the command line gave the following error: `sudo apt-get install libx11-6:i386`.

It seems that it cannot detect packages from other arch type.

I already did the following:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libx11-6:i386
```

Checking from the Synaptic package manager, it does not display any packages/library from i386 architecture. How to install library from other architecture?

The system I'm running in is NVIDIA jetson tx1 with L4T R28.2. It's based on ARM64 and I need to run Arduino IDE which is based on ARM32.

---

source.list:

```
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ xenial main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src {---} xenial main restricted universe multiverse

deb {---} xenial-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src {---} xenial-updates main restricted universe multiverse

deb {---} xenial universe
deb-src {---} xenial universe
deb {---} xenial-updates universe
deb-src {---} xenial-updates universe

deb {---} xenial-backports main restricted
deb-src {---} xenial-backports main restricted

deb {---} xenial-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src {---} xenial-security main restricted universe multiverse
```

Regards,
Kezia

Answer (score 0):

This is available libc6-i386 here https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libc6-i386
or if its still not showing maybe the repo is not install. Else you can do a simple workaround https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30451939/cant-install-libc6-package

Comment: Thanks Jatin-CBS, now it's able to locate the library, however there're unmet dependencies that prevent me to install it `The following packages have unmet dependencies: libc6-i386:amd64 : Depends: libc6:amd64 (= 2.23-0ubuntu10) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
` Is there any way to force install the library?